# wordpress text image slider with right side navigation?

Tags: jquery-plugins, wordpress

i need this slider plugin. i have searched a lots of plugins but nothing find similiar it. after lots of efforts i found 
`"unpointzero slider wordpress plugin"`.
 but its not configure properly.

kindly help me.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try http://slidervilla.com/pointelle/ . This showed up in a quick google search. I'm sure there are plenty more.

Comment: Another option might be http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-content-slideshow/ based on your requirement.